# Regex to replace a string from one place to another in the same record

Tags: php, regex

I have a record separated by `|` symbol. I need to replace a string from one place to another in the same record:

My input looks like this:
`BANG|ADAR|**285815**|MOTOR|GOOD||INDIA|2.4|SOFTWARE|285816_AKS|SAB_PART|**AKS_PN|285816**`

I need to replace `285815` with the string after `AKS_PN`, in this case I need to replace `285815` with `285816`.

With the `(([^|]*\|){3})(.*)` I am able to fetch `285815`, need help in fetching string after `AKS_PN` in the same regular expression.

I am aware of how to replace `285815` with `285816`. I am using PHP.

Comment: Look into using capture groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Regex solution

You need to use capturing groups. In general:

```
(everything_before)(interesting_part_1)(between)(interesting_part_in_the_end)
```

Afterwards, just put it together as you wish

```
(everything_before)(interesting_part_in_the_end)(between)
```

This leaves `(interesting_part_1)` out of the final string.

---

In your specific example this might come down to

```
^((?:[^|]*\|){2})([^|]*)\|(.*?AKS_PN)\|(.*)
```

which would need to be replaced by

```
$1$4|$3
```

See an [**example on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GfE8Zm/1/) (still not sure what to do with `285815` here).

---

Everything in `PHP`:

```
<?php

$string = "BANG|ADAR|285815|MOTOR|GOOD||INDIA|2.4|SOFTWARE|285816_AKS|SAB_PART|AKS_PN|285816";

$regex = '~^((?:[^|]*\|){2})([^|]*)\|(.*?AKS_PN)\|(.*)~';

$string = preg_replace($regex, "$1$4|$3", $string);
echo $string;
# BANG|ADAR|285816|MOTOR|GOOD||INDIA|2.4|SOFTWARE|285816_AKS|SAB_PART|AKS_PN
?>
```

---

## Non-regex solution

You don't even need a regular expression here (far too complicated), just split, switch and join afterwards:

```
<?php

$string = "BANG|ADAR|285815|MOTOR|GOOD||INDIA|2.4|SOFTWARE|285816_AKS|SAB_PART|AKS_PN|285816";

$parts = explode("|", $string);
$parts[2] = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
$string = implode("|", $parts);

echo $string;
?>
```